# Is this the correct way of implementing a builder pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Coming from a Javascript background, and just now getting into c++. Want to know if im doing the builder pattern correctly in C++, and also what could improve on ?

**PongObject.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
class PongObject{
    private:
        int objectHeight;
        int objectWidth;
        int offset;
        int objectScreenHeight;
        Color objectColor;
public:
    void setPongObjectWidth(int width){
        this->objectWidth = width;
    }
    void setPongObjectHeight(int height){
        this->objectHeight = height;
    }
    void setPongObjectOffset(int offset){
        this->offset = offset;
    }
    void setPongObjectScreenHeight(int screenHeight){
        this->objectScreenHeight = screenHeight;
    }
    void setPongObjectColor(Color color){
        this->objectColor = color;
    }
    void build(){
        DrawRectangle(offset, objectScreenHeight, objectWidth, objectHeight, objectColor);
    }
};
```

**PongObjectBuilder.cpp**

```
class PongBuilder: PongObject{
public:
    PongBuilder& setWidth(int width){
        this->setPongObjectWidth(width);
        return *this;
    }
    PongBuilder& setHeight(int height){
        this->setPongObjectHeight(height);
        return *this;
    }
    PongBuilder& setOffset(int offset){
        this->setPongObjectOffset(offset);
        return *this;
    }
    PongBuilder& setScreenHeight(int screenHeight){
        this->setPongObjectScreenHeight(screenHeight);
        return *this;
    }
    PongBuilder& setPongColor(Color color){
        this->setPongObjectColor(color);
        return *this;
    }
    PongBuilder& buildObject(){
        this->build();
        return *this;
    }

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(void){
    GameWindow window(1000, 1000);
    SetTargetFPS(60);
    window.setWindow();
    PongBuilder* pongObj1 = new PongBuilder();
    PongBuilder* pongObj2 = new PongBuilder();
    int pong1Y = GetScreenHeight() / 2 - 50;
    int pong2Y = GetScreenHeight() / 2 - 50;
    const int someOffset = GetScreenWidth() - 100 - 50;
    while(!WindowShouldClose()){
        ClearBackground(BLACK);
        BeginDrawing();
        pongObj1->setWidth(100).setHeight(100).setOffset(50).setScreenHeight(pong1Y).setPongColor(RAYWHITE).buildObject();
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_A)){
            pong1Y -= 500 * GetFrameTime();
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_S)){
            pong1Y += 500 * GetFrameTime();
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_D)){
            pong2Y-= 500 * GetFrameTime();
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_F)){
            pong2Y += 500 * GetFrameTime();
        }
       
        pongObj2->setWidth(100).setHeight(100).setOffset(someOffset).setScreenHeight(pong2Y).setPongColor(BLUE).buildObject();
        EndDrawing();
    }
    
    delete pongObj1;
    delete pongObj2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you got the idea wrong:
**Builder is a *creational* design pattern that lets you construct complex objects step by step.**

Builder is not supposed to be a subclass of the object you are building.
It's a utility class whose only purpose is to *create* objects, don't use it to alter them after creation or for unrelated tasks such as drawing.

This misuse leads to performance problems: you're setting width, height, offset and color every frame even though they never change.

You can find a good c++ example with explanation [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder/cpp/example).

Unrelated comments regarding your code:

- Don't use `using namespace std;`, it's like a wildcard import, will lead to name collisions.
- Your `private` block of `PongObject` is indented too much, make sure to reformat your code to make it more readable.
- No need to create your objects on the heap when you can do it on the stack. Just remove `new` keywords from object creation lines and you won't need to `del` them afterwards.

Comment: How would i rewrite this in such a way, that it follows a builder pattern ? Thanks for the feedback. I learn a bit better when things are refactored.

Comment: @BARNOWL you don't need this pattern here since `PongObject` doesn't make sense if some of its fields are not initialized. It is used with classes that have several *optional* fields. I linked a good example of its use in the answer.

Comment: Yeah i seen that before, i can't seem to wrap my head around that example, but yeah will look at other examples. Thanks for sharing though.